# Test email sending functionality without the need of invoking a controller method

Tags: symfony, testing, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

When I looked over [this](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/testing.html) piece of  symfony's documentation, I realized that the actual test is being done on a controller.

In my case what I want to test is a custom function in a service for example:

```
class MyMailService
{

 public function __construct(SwiftMailer $mailer)
 {
   $this->mailer=$mailer;
 }


 public function sendHelloEmail($from,$to)
 {
   $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setBody('I can see stars');

    $this->mailer->send($message);
 }

}
```

So how I can test whether the application sends  an email without the need to invoke client tests?

Comment: Configure `config` file `test` environment first to store the email in `spool` directory and then check if the email is actually in the `spool` directory or not. The whole example can be found [here](Testing emails with checking spool directory in behat). All you have to do is extract the code from `FeatureContext` file. It should be easy!

Comment: You can always create Symfony command that invokes your services' `sendHelloEmail()` method.

Comment: I've just realised that the URL is missing in  my comment above here it is. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/nv3f/testing-emails-with-checking-spool-directory-in-behat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BentCoder suggested you can use the approach ot having the mails stored in the spool directory and check if message exists. In order to identify use a custom header. In my case I have just places a common name in an `X-Agent` header.

My sending email service code is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use AppBundle\Interfaces\EmailSenderInterface;
use \Swift_Mailer;
use \Swift_Message;

class NormalEmailSend implements EmailSenderInterface
{

  /**
  * @var Swift_Mailer
  */
  private $mailer=null;

  public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $mailer)
  {
    $this->mailer=$mailer;
  }

  /**
  * @inheritdoc
  */
  public function send($from,$to,$title="",$bodyPlain="",$bodyHtml="",array $cc=[],array $bcc=[])
  {

    $message=new Swift_Message($title);
    $message->setFrom($from)->setTo($to)->setBody($bodyPlain,'text/plain');

    if($bodyHtml){
        $message->addPart($bodyHtml,'text/html');
    }

    $headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-Agent','ellakcy_member_app');

    return $this->mailer->send($message);
  }


}
```

And the Test is:

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use \Swift_Message;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

use AppBundle\Services\NormalEmailSend;

/**
* @testype functional
*/
class ContactEmailSendTest extends KernelTestCase
{

   /**
   * @var AppBundle\Services\NormalEmailSend
   */
   private $service;

   /**
   * @var String
   */
   private $spoolPath=null;

    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
     protected function setUp()
     {
         $kernel = self::bootKernel();
         $container = $kernel->getContainer();
         $this->service = $container->get(NormalEmailSend::class);
         $this->spoolPath = $container->getParameter('swiftmailer.spool.default.file.path');
     }

    public function testSendEmail()
    {
       $from='sender@example.com';
       $to='receiver@example.com';
       $this->service->send($from,$to,'Hello','Hello','Hello');
       $this->checkEmail();
    }

    private function checkEmail()
    {
      $spoolDir = $this->getSpoolDir();
      $filesystem = new Filesystem();

      if ($filesystem->exists($spoolDir)) {
          $finder = new Finder();
          $finder->in($spoolDir)
                 ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
                ->files();

          if(!$finder->hasResults()){
            $this->fail('No email has been sent');
          }

          $counter=0;
          foreach ($finder as $file) {
              /** @var Swift_Message $message */
              $message = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
              $header = $message->getHeaders()->get('X-Agent');
              $this->assertEquals($header->getValue(),'ellakcy_member_app');
              $counter++;
          }

          //@todo Possibly Consinder not doing this check
          if($counter===0){
              $this->fail('No email has been sent');
          }

      } else {
        $this->fail('On test environment the emails should be spooled and not actuallt be sent');
      }
    }


    /**
    * {@inheritDoc}
    */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $spoolDir = $this->getSpoolDir();
        $filesystem = new Filesystem();
        $filesystem->remove($spoolDir);
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    private function getSpoolDir()
    {
      return $this->spoolPath;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps, also you can modify the code seen above in order to place a tracking number via `X-Mail-Id` and place it upon your function's sending parameters as an optional one in case that the number is not null you can set it as header.

So when you traverse the spool directory you can mark emails that are going to be send via its tracking number.

Answer (score -1):

> So how I can test whether the application sends an email without the need to invoke client tests?

There is no need to do that. Testing whether mails are sent or not falls in the domain of functional or even system integration testing (since whether the mails are actually sent or not also depends on mail environment configuration, network, etc.). If you just want to check whether your mails are correctly structured, you can unit test the service if you separate the actual message creation from the message sending.

Comment: This is what I want too do to have some test cases where I can check whether this function works or not so I can mock it easily and  then do the actual Unit test. What I need first is to create a more mockable entities and test it with functional and integration tests so then I can test the rest of the code via Unit tests.